# What is the way to know a Zope permission title by knowing its id (and vice-versa)?

Tags: permissions, plone, zope, zope3

On Zope and Plone you can register permissions like this:

```xml
<permission
   id="choosen.id.for.your.permission"
   title="Old Zope 2 permission, shown in ZMI"
   />
```

What is the way to get the permission's title from Python when you know the permission's id?

I mean something like:

```
>>> something_magic.get('choosen.id.for.your.permission')
'Old Zope 2 permission, shown in ZMI'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Permissions are registered as [`zope.security.interfaces.IPermission`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.security/blob/master/src/zope/security/interfaces.py#L302-L319) utilities by their id; you can thus look them up by their ids by using [`zope.component.getUtility()`](http://docs.zope.org/zope.component/api/utility.html#zope.component.getUtility):

```
from zope.component import getUtility
from zope.security.interfaces import IPermission

permission = getUtility(IPermission, name=u'choosen.id.for.your.permission')
print permission.title
```

To go the other way, from title to id, you need to search all utilities:

```
from zope.component import getUtilitiesFor
from zope.security.interfaces import IPermission

searched_title = u'Old Zope 2 permission, shown in ZMI'
name = next((name for name, p in getUtilitiesFor(IPermission)
             if p.title == searched_title), None)
```

Comment: For some reason it was not working for me, but probably I was using a wrong id. Thanks!

So what is quicker way to get the id from the title?

Comment: I don't think there is one; you'd have to list all utilities and search: `next((name for name, p in getUtilitiesFor(IPermission) if p.title == searched_title), None)` will return the name or `None` if there isn't any such permission.